# One Column in Query Result Displayed messily

Tags: sql, oracle

When I tried to use 'select in select' in oracle DBMS, one of the columns is totally messy, for example, in table ID, after query, one of the columns is class1, the result can't display it properly. Like shown below. It is totally messy and the value of one column appears in another one. Just wondering has somebody has the same question before?

Thanks a lot.
This is what I get now. It should be 'Equity' instead of 'ÉquityEquity','FixedIncome' instead of 'Fi'

[image]

```
id |    class1     | class2
01 |    stocks     | us_stock
02 |      st       | ETF
03 |    ocksOt     |Direct_Investment
03 |hersOthersOthe |Direct_Investment


-- Select the market value for each category according to asset_class_level2 and asset_class_level1
SELECT  
    SHEET1.TRADE_DATE,
    SHEET3.Asset_Class_1,
    SHEET3.Asset_Class_2,
    SUM(SHEET1.MV1) AS SUM_MV

FROM
    (
    --used to select the sum of mv for each stock
    SELECT 
        MAX(JD_RISK.NAME) AS NAME1,
        SUM(JD_RISK.MV_USD) AS MV1,
        JD_RISK.TRADE_DATE AS TRADE_DATE,
        JD_RISK.BB_UNIQUE_ID AS BB_UNIQUE_ID1
    FROM JD_RISK
    GROUP BY  JD_RISK.TRADE_DATE,JD_RISK.BB_UNIQUE_ID
    ) SHEET1

LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
    SHEET2.NAME,
    SHEET2.BB_UNIQUE_ID2,
    SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS,
    SHEET2.FUND_ASSET_CLASS_FOCUS,
    SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE,
    SHEET2.TAG_LEVEL_2,
    SHEET2.ACCOUNT_CODE,
    SHEET2.SECURITY_TYPE,
    SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1,
    CASE
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Hedge_Fund' THEN 'Hedge_Fund'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Private_Equity' and SHEET2.NAME LIKE '.F_%' THEN 'PE_Fund'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Private_Equity' and SHEET2.NAME NOT LIKE '.F_%' THEN 'Direct_Investment'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Commodity' THEN 'Commodity'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Real_Estate' and SHEET2.TAG_LEVEL_2 = 'HOTEL' THEN 'Hotel'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Real_Estate' and SHEET2.TAG_LEVEL_2 = 'COMMERCIAL' THEN 'Commercial'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Real_Estate' and SHEET2.TAG_LEVEL_2 = 'FUND' THEN 'Fund' 
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Real_Estate' and SHEET2.TAG_LEVEL_2 = 'RESIDENCIAL' THEN 'Residencial'
        --not sure
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Real_Estate' and SHEET2.TAG_LEVEL_2 IS NULL THEN 'Others'


        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Currency' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE = 'Cash' THEN 'Cash'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Currency' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE = 'Foreign Exchange Forward' THEN 'Forward'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Currency' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE = 'Credit Default Swap' THEN 'CDS'

        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Equity' and SHEET2.SECURITY_TYPE IN ('Common Stock','ADR','MLP','Unit','Stapled Security')  
         THEN 'Common_Stock'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Equity' and SHEET2.SECURITY_TYPE = 'Prefer Stock' THEN 'Prefer_Stock'
        -----------------------------------------

        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Equity' and SHEET2.SECURITY_TYPE = 'Equity Option' THEN 'Option'

        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Equity' and SHEET2.SECURITY_TYPE = 'ETP' THEN 'ETF'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Equity' and SHEET2.SECURITY_TYPE IN ('Open-End Fund','Closed-End Fund') THEN 'Mutual_Fund'

        --not sure
        --WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Equity Option' THEN 'Option'
        --WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Hedge_Fund' then 'others'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fund' and SHEET2.TAG_LEVEL_1 = 'JUNSON' THEN 'JSG'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fund' and SHEET2.TAG_LEVEL_1 in ('WESTFIELD','WELD','TCIM','JOMON') THEN 'Private_Equity'


        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE = 'Corporate Bond' THEN 'Corporate_Bond'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE = 'Convertible Bond' THEN 'Convertible_Bond'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE = 'Treasury' THEN 'Government_Bond'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE = 'Swaption' THEN 'Swaption'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE = 'Swaption' THEN 'Swaption'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE like 'Rec%' THEN 'IR_Swap'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE like 'Pay%' THEN 'IR_Swap'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE like 'CDS%' THEN 'CDS'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_TYPE like 'Mortgage Backed Security' THEN 'MBS'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS = 'Fund' and SHEET2.SECURITY_TYPE NOT in ('ETP')
         THEN 'Mutual_Fund'
        WHEN SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS_1 = 'Fixed_Income' and SHEET2.ASSET_CLASS = 'Fund' and SHEET2.SECURITY_TYPE = 'ETP'
         THEN 'ETF' 
          ELSE 'Others'
           END Asset_class_2
        FROM
    (
       SELECT
           MAX(ID1.NAME) AS NAME,
           ID1.BB_UNIQUE_ID AS BB_UNIQUE_ID2,
           MAX(ID1.ASSET_ClASS) AS ASSET_CLASS, 
           MAX(ID1.FUND_ASSET_CLASS_FOCUS) AS FUND_ASSET_CLASS_FOCUS,
           MAX(ID1.ASSET_TYPE) AS ASSET_TYPE,
           MAX(ID1.TAG_LEVEL_2) AS TAG_LEVEL_2,
           MAX(ID1.SECURITY_TYPE) AS SECURITY_TYPE,
           MAX(ID1.ACCOUNT_CODE) AS ACCOUNT_CODE,
           MAX(ID1.TAG_LEVEL_1) AS TAG_LEVEL_1,
    --Tag all the assets with a label of asset_class_1
           CASE 
         WHEN MAX(ID1.ASSET_CLASS) = 'Currency' THEN 'Currency'
         WHEN MAX(ID1.ACCOUNT_CODE) = 'JD_FUND' THEN 'Hedge_Fund'
         WHEN MAX(ID1.ACCOUNT_CODE) = 'DIRINV' THEN 'Private_Equity'
           ELSE(
                      CASE 
                    WHEN MAX(ID1.ACCOUNT_CODE) = 'REAL_EST' THEN 'Real_Estate'
                        --WHEN (ID1.ACCOUNT_CODE = 'DIRINV' AND ID1.NAME LIKE '.F_%') THEN 'Fund'
                       ELSE
                        (
                      CASE 
                          -- WHEN ID1.ASSET_CLASS = 'Currency' THEN 'Currency'
                    WHEN MAX(ID1.ASSET_CLASS) = 'Equity' 
                          OR (MAX(ID1.ASSET_CLASS) = 'Fund' AND MAX(ID1.FUND_ASSET_CLASS_FOCUS) = 'Equity')
                          OR (MAX(ID1.ASSET_CLASS) = 'Option' OR MAX(ID1.ASSET_CLASS) = 'Warrant')
                          OR (MAX(ID1.ASSET_CLASS) = 'Future' AND MAX(ID1.ASSET_TYPE) = 'Equity Index')
                      THEN 'Equity'
                    WHEN MAX(ID1.ASSET_CLASS) = 'FixedIncome' 
                          OR (MAX(ID1.ASSET_CLASS) = 'Fund' and MAX(ID1.FUND_ASSET_CLASS_FOCUS) = 'Fixed Income')
                          OR (MAX(ID1.ASSET_CLASS) = 'Future' and MAX(ID1.ASSET_TYPE) = 'Bond Future')
                     THEN 'Fixed_Income'
                    WHEN MAX(ID1.ASSET_CLASS) = 'Fund' and MAX(ID1.FUND_ASSET_CLASS_FOCUS) = 'Commodity'
                     THEN 'Commodity'
                       ELSE 'Others'
                       END)
                END) 
            END
            Asset_Class_1 
         FROM 
        JD_ID  ID1
       GROUP BY ID1.BB_UNIQUE_ID  -- make sure each asset only be classified once
    ) SHEET2
    ) SHEET3 
ON 
    SHEET1.BB_UNIQUE_ID1 = SHEET3.BB_UNIQUE_ID2
GROUP BY 
    SHEET1.TRADE_DATE, SHEET3.Asset_Class_1, SHEET3.Asset_Class_2
ORDER BY 
    TRADE_DATE,ASSET_CLASS_1,ASSET_CLASS_2
```

Comment: Show your query that produces the result.

Comment: And what is totally messy?  What is the expected results?

Comment: Which tool do you use? The one that produces that mess?

Comment: Hi, the expected result of class1 should be like 'stocks', 'Others' instead of 'st' or 'hersOthersothe'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used sql query in oracle database management system.

Comment: You need to show us the **actual query** you run. Also some sample raw data which reproduces the problem. Although if I were to bet my money would be on *the underlying data values messed up and your query is working as expected*.

Comment: Can you please paste the actual data in the table, query used to fetch the data and issue with the data in question itself and not image?

Comment: Sure, I have pasted the code and the actual result is shown in the image

Comment: Hi, is anybody still there?

Comment: Tejash is not asking for the result, they're asking for the raw starting data.  Without seeing that, no one can help you.